How to use virtual environments in Jupyter Notebook in VS Code
I use Jupyter extension (v2024.10.0), Python (v2024.20.0), and Pylance (v2024.12.1) with default interpreter path, VS Code 1.95.3 on MacOS Sonoma 14.6. I want to debug Python code interactively in jupyter notebooks using the same virtual environment I use when running modules via Terminal.
e.g. I have a project with these files:

test.ipynb
script.py

I run my script like this:
$ source ~/envs/my-project-env/bin/activate
(my-project-env) $ python script.py

I would like to use my-project-env environment in the Jupyter notebook. I click Select Kernel top right, but it doesn't appear in the drop-down.

Next I try the tip here and use ipython kernel install --user --name=my-project-env. It creates the kernel, and I can select it from the Jupyter Kernel... list instead, but it uses the wrong Python path, pointing to my global default interpreter instead.
Next I try this tip, added my python interpreter by adding my executable's path to the list of Python Interpreters. This works great for creating a dedicated terminal for running the script.py. No need for manually sourcing my environment anymore:

But the kernel is still unavailable for selection in Jupyter Notebook "Select Kernel" list. How can I run the Jupyter Notebook and get the same code auto-completion using the same environment as my script?

did you activate the environment before installing ipykernel and doing ipython kernel install --user --name=my-project-env? I bet you didn't and you did it using the default environment

The only way I could figure this out was by creating a new Python environment via "Create Python Environment" option in Select Kernel menu:

This created a virtual environment called ".venv" in the root of my project folder, which is available for use with both my scripts and the Jupyter Kernel.
!which python

import sys
sys.executable

both display expected results, and packages can be imported no problem.
It's a decent solution, although I'd rather be able to re-use an existing environment in many cases.
